# Bind SSL to Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I have created node js api and hosted it in Azure Container Instance using registry. I am using my API using FQDN. Now I want to bind SSL Certificate to this instance. Is there any way to do so? I searched for solution but didn't found any.

Comment: How are you hosting the container instance ? If using Azure App service you can offload the SSL cert deployment and binding to the App Service.

Comment: I am not using Azure App Service. I am using Azure Container instance as a service and docker image pulling from Azure Container Registry.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a container group with an application container and a sidecar container running an SSL provider.

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl), you will do these:

- [Create a self-signed certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl#create-a-self-signed-certificate). For production scenarios, you should obtain a certificate from a certificate authority.
- Configure Nginx to use SSL. You create a configuration file for Nginx to use SSL. Base64-encode the Nginx configuration file, the SSL certificate, and the SSL key. Then, you enter the encoded contents in a YAML file used to deploy the container group.
- [Deploy container group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl#deploy-container-group) by specifying the container configurations in a YAML file.

For example, you could edit the following YAML file to meet your requirements.

```
api-version: 2018-10-01
location: westus
name: app-with-ssl
properties:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-with-ssl
    properties:
      image: nginx
      ports:
      - port: 443
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
      volumeMounts:
      - name: nginx-config
        mountPath: /etc/nginx
  - name: my-app
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld
      ports:
      - port: 80
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
  volumes:
  - secret:
      ssl.crt: <Enter contents of base64-ssl.crt here>
      ssl.key: <Enter contents of base64-ssl.key here>
      nginx.conf: <Enter contents of base64-nginx.conf here>
    name: nginx-config
  ipAddress:
    ports:
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
    type: Public
  osType: Linux
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Comment: how to replace  mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld with our image